# Ваш любимый способ центрировать div в div?

Tags: вёрстка, html5, css3, оптимизация

Какие самые эффективные, красивые и изящные способы выполнить задачу вы знаете?
Чем пользуетесь и что советуете? Максимально оптимальные способы.

Comment: css )) margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Это ж только горизонтальное центрирование?)

Comment: Вопрос нормальный. Переформулировать при желании можно, но я считаю стилистические правки бессмысленными. Суть вопроса ясна и неизменна, конкретные ответы можно дать.

Comment: display table --> display table-cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если без флексов и нужно центровать по-вертикали и по-горизонтали, то

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Ну и HTML кусочек какой-то такой:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Преимущество такого способа в том, что содержимое может иметь большие размеры, чем контейнер, но при этом центровка не нарушится и размеры контейнера не "поплывут".

PS. Мне кажется это очевидным, но все-таки напишу, что данное решение можно "разделить по осям". То есть отдельно центрировать только по-горизонтали или отдельно по-вертикали. Для этого нужно использовать соответственно только `left` или `top` и заменить `translate` соответственно на `translateX` или `translateY`.

Comment: А если с флексами? :)

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron А если с ними, то в соседнем ответе ссылочка на подробное описание. Наверняка будет некорректно, если я тут буду приводить пример.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь flexbox контейнерами

Подробная информация по теме:

http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Без кода было лучше. Советую поправить код, а то и до минуса недолго.

Comment: Для кроссбраузерности https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autoprefixer

Comment: Qwertiy, поправил, спасибо. Не самый удачный пример, согласен.

Comment: все-равно интересная информация