# Центрирование текста по вертикали с неизвестными данными вообще

Tags: html, css, строки

Доброго времени суток!
Интересуюсь возможностью центрирования строчного элемента внутри блока с неизвестной высотой, который внутри блока с неизвестной высотой.
Я к тому, что пересмотрел множество ресурсов и вопросов здесь, все ведут на то, что если задана высота родительского блока или хотя бы блока родителя родительского блока, то все работает.
И это верно.
А что, если у меня такой CSS-код:

```
#preloader {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.loader {
    position: absolute;
}
```

И такой HTML:

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div class="loader">  
        <span id="loader_txt">Здесь текст</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я специально не оставил в коде намеков на строчные элементы, потому что это очевидно. Я спрашиваю немного по-философски. Если высоты неизвестны, остается только прибегать к JS? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Центрировать контент в "неизвестности" можно при помощи [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

В вашем случае будет вот так:

```
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);

    display: flex; /* Магия */
    align-items: center; /* Центрируем по вертикали */
    justify-content: center; /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
}
```

**Демо: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42f10edL/1/)**

Несколько интересных ресурсов по flexbox:

1. [Практическое применение FlexBox](http://habrahabr.ru/post/242545/)
2. [caniuse, поддержка браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)
3. [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Согласен, но ведь display:flex не работает в некоторых браузерах, да? Все равно спасибо за идею.

Comment: Я дал ссылку на caniuse, поддержка есть во всех браузерах, и в IE начиная с IE 10. Если вы не разрабатываете веб приложения для использования в гос. секторе, то можно смело использовать.

Comment: :)) Благодарю, буду смело.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы вы поискали по сайту, то нашли бы уйму вариантов. Например мой
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466863/177613

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**

Решение без явного указания размеров, которое я использую, когда нужно выровнять блок по вертикали, но его конечная высота неизвестна. Работает даже в IE9. Пример:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
.container-fluid:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Блок, который нужно выровнять */
.row {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**

Проще всего выравнивание сделать с использованием Flexbox, однако этот вариант не поддерживает IE 9:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```