# Не получается отредактировать позицию текста в блоке

Tags: javascript, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 window.onload = function() {
    var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
    var circIn = document.querySelectorAll(".circle__inv");
    var circInCnt = document.querySelectorAll(".count__hgt");
    for(var i = 0;i<circle.length;i++) {
        circle[i].style.height = circle[i].offsetWidth + "px";
        circIn[i].paddingTop = circIn[i].paddingTop - circInCnt.offsetHeight "px";
    }
}

    .circle {
    width:  15%;
    background: #900C3F;
    border-radius:  50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:  18px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}


.circle__inv {
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:    50%;
}
```

Текст должен быть по середине по вертикали и горизонтали, недостаточная точность позиционирования по вертикали(ошибка в моем коде). Скорее всего она в js(перепутал значения, объекты). Прошу помочь, очень важно

Comment: Почитайте  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466836 или воcпользуйтесь поиском по сайту (искать css центрирование по-вертикали)

Comment: Не подходит к данной проблеме, быть может я не так понял? Заранее прошу прощения, новенький, тупенький

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если всё, что вам нужно, это центрировать текст вертикально в этом круге, то не изобретайте колесо. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLxweL).

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>Выберите интересующую тему</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  background: #900C3F;
  border-radius: 50%;

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;

  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, использовал данный материал, но есть пара вопросов:    1) не понял, для чего margin-top: 50%; нужен span'у, работает без этого (быть может это все-таки для чего-то другого? Ведь теоретически лучше давать padding родителям) 2)Почему вы убрали адаптивность из блока(круга). За ранее благодарю, уменьшил  данную секцию javascript

Comment: @amazingman216 1. Откройте ссылку на CodePen, что в моём ответе, уберите там margin-top, работать перестанет. Задавать padding родителю не лучше. Мы позиционируем текст внутри этого блока. Вдруг вам захочется что-то ещё засунуть в этот круг, что не нужно будет позиционировать таким образом? 2. Потому что это пример. Если вам нужна адаптивность — сделайте :)